# Salesforce REST API - returns 401 not authorized

Tags: salesforce

I am writing a simple application that can query salesforce data from the web using Javascript[JQuery/Angular]. I have tried to follow all the steps outlined (https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/) but keep getting a 401 (not authorized) error when I make any call that requires a token.

I have a connected app set up with the following OAuth policies:

OAuth policies
    Permitted Users: All users may self-authorize 
    IP Restrictions: Relax IP restrictions
    Require Users to Log In: Every time they use this application
    This application has permission to: Provide access to your data via the Web
    This application has permission to: Access and manage your data

I am following the User Agent Flow as follows:

```
var url = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?";
url += "response_type=token";
url += "&client_id="{my application id}";  // removed for this post
url += "&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8443/obsandbox/connect.html";
url += "&display=popup";
url += "&scope=api web";
window.location = url;
```

This flow seems to work corrected and I get to the login page and am redirected as below

```
https://localhost:8443/obsandbox/connect.html
    #access_token={XXXXX_the_access_token}
    &instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fna15.salesforce.com
    &id={sf issued id}
    &issued_at=1397587022117
    &signature=giX8JA%2BFqqBlDDsv6jn21Z7c0%2BKvlfvbtUxxsSVVqKs%3D
    &scope=web
```

I then issue a cross domain javascript call to salesforce but neither the get resources not the query calls work. I've tried them using both JQuery and Angular with the same result - 401 Not Authorized.

By the way I have tried using both "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token & "OAuth " + token.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated

Raj

Using JQuery

```
function sfRes(iElm, tElm) {
var instance = document.getElementById(iElm).value;
var token = document.getElementById(tElm).value;
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    url : instance + "/services/data/v29.0/",
    beforeSend : function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    },
    crossDomain : true,
    success : function(ret) {
        console.log(ret);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error: ' + jqXHR.status);
        console.log('ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
}

function sfQuery(iElm, qElm, tElm) {
var instance = document.getElementById(iElm).value;
var query = document.getElementById(qElm).value;
var token = document.getElementById(tElm).value;
return $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    url : instance + "/services/data/v29.0/query/",
    data : {
        "q" : query
    },
    beforeSend : function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    },
    crossDomain : true,
    success : function(ret) {
        console.log(ret);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error: ' + jqXHR.status);
        console.log('ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

Using Angular

```
$scope.sfRes = function(iElm, tElm) {
    var instance = document.getElementById(iElm).value;
    var token = document.getElementById(tElm).value;
    return $http({
        method : "JSONP",
        url : instance + "/services/data/v29.0/",
        headers : {
            "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token,
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return "Failed";
    });
}, 
$scope.sfQuery = function(iElm, qElm, tElm) {
    var instance = document.getElementById(iElm).value;
    var query = document.getElementById(qElm).value;
    var token = document.getElementById(tElm).value;
    return $http({
        method : "JSONP",
        url : instance + "/services/data/v29.0/query/",
        params : {
            "q" : query
        },
        headers : {
            "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token,
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response;
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked if the user you're using to connect to the org has execute permissions on the apex class that is hosted as a REST service?